“Hast dein Schutzschild genommen” – why not “deinen”?
This is from the song Kämpferherz by Pietro Lombardi:

Hast dein Schutzschild genommen, jedes Feuer abgewehrt.
Will mir nicht vorstellen wie es ohne dich wär’.

I’m curious why he uses dein. Shouldn’t it be deinen?

"Schild" is one of the many substantives in German that occur in multiple genders - here in m and n. There is a bit of confusion in dictionaries (and common usage) on whether the gender changes the meaning: Duden says m is the shield while n is the sign. Originally, it used to be the same thing. Wiktionary, Grimm and other dictionaries mean n can mean both and Grimm even says "both means (or at least used to mean) both" (my opinion and experience is m is the shield while n can mean both shield and sign). For the latter, there might, however be a bit of a north/south difference as well.

That was an excellent answer. Thank you so much! (Now I have to start glueing back in all the hair I had pulled out.)

@MarkThomsen Then remember Glatze as a somewhat pejorative expression for a bald head.

TIL that me getting angry at n being used for shield lacks foundation. Thanks!

I'm not sure if the entry in Grimm's dictionary supports the claim that neuter Schild can mean both "shield" and "sign". The latter is described only in sub-entry (10): "schild vorm hause, zum zeichen des dort betriebenen gewerbes" (i.e. basically a commercial sign in front of a building), and apparently neuter gender is restricted to only this sub-entry ("in neuerer sprache braucht man schild in diesem sinne meist, doch nicht ausschlieszlich, mit neutralem geschlechte"). The very general contemporary meaning is unattested in Grimm's.

@Schmuddi In the other entries, he talks of clypeus/scutum and signum - shield and sign. It's just hidden a bit better, but still there.

You are right, it should be “deinen”, accusative masculine. Often “dein” and “deinen” are hard to distinguish (deinen -> dein’n -> dein’), but I also hear “dein”. Therefore this may be a confusion between “der Schild” (shield) and “das Schild” (sign as in “Straßenschild”). To be honest, at first reading it didn’t sound wrong to me.

+1 and pretty sure also the singer in question would make this mistake in a song (personal opinion). Additionally, this can sometimes be deliberately done in songs in order to align the amount of syllables for clearer rhymes (e.g. this is done in rap quite often)
